# AWS Latency in opening ports?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, windows-server-2016

I recently wrote a C# console application server and client, which I am demonstrating on an AWS EC2 Instance of Windows 2016 Server. It uses a special port I defined 9314 over TCP. I have added the port number and allowed addresses from everyone to inbound traffic.

When I run the application server on the remote desktop, it connects and listens fine on its internal ip port, or so it tells me. When I start my client on my desktop, and connect to the public ip and port I provide, it timesout always... Is this possibly because the settings haven't "sticked" yet?

Comment: *connects and listens fine on its internal ip port, or so it tells me*  What is an "internal IP port?"  Is it listening on 0.0.0.0:9314? ...or something else?

Comment: You probably forgot to open the port in the AWS security group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allow 9314 port from windows firewall as well to access from your machine or disable windows firewall and try. Hope it will work sure.